# How to stop Timer when count equals 12

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working through the unity tutorials and I was wondering how to stop a timer when you hit 12 of count.
I currently have two scripts I am using.

1. PlayerController

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using TMPro;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
 
 
  public float speed;
  public TextMeshProUGUI countText;
  public GameObject winTextObject;
  

  private float movementX;
  private float movementY;

  private Rigidbody rb;
  private int count;

  // At the start of the game..
  void Start()
  {

    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();


    count = 0;

    SetCountText();

    winTextObject.SetActive(false);




  }

  void FixedUpdate()
  {
    // Create a Vector3 variable, and assign X and Z to feature the horizontal and vertical float variables above
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(movementX, 0.0f, movementY);

    rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
  }

  void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
  {
    // ..and if the GameObject you intersect has the tag 'Pick Up' assigned to it..
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pickup"))
    {
      other.gameObject.SetActive(false);

      // Add one to the score variable 'count'
      count = count + 1;

      // Run the 'SetCountText()' function (see below)
      SetCountText();
    }
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("SpeedPickup"))
    {
      other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
      speed = speed + 25;
      count = count + 1;
    }
  }

  void OnMove(InputValue value)
  {
    Vector2 v = value.Get<Vector2>();

    movementX = v.x;
    movementY = v.y;
  }

  void SetCountText()
  {
    countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString();
    if (count >= 12)
    {
      winTextObject.SetActive(true);

    }

  }

}
```

And a second script Timer.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;


public class Timer : MonoBehaviour

{
  [SerializeField]
  private TextMeshProUGUI timerUILabel; //drag UI Text object here via Inspector

  private float t_offset = 0f; // set to nothing, can be set to an offset if needed.
  private int t_minutes;
  private int t_seconds;
  private int t_milliseconds;
  private bool finished = false;
  

  private void Update()
  {
    float t = Time.time - t_offset;
    //Debug.Log("currentTime in seconds = " + t);

    t_minutes = ((int)t / 60); // t(seconds) / 60 = total minutes
    t_seconds = ((int)t % 60); // t(seconds) % 60 = remaining seconds 
    t_milliseconds = ((int)(t * 100)) % 100; // (total seconds * 1000) % 1000 = remaining milliseconds

    //display the text in a 00:00:00 format
    timerUILabel.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", t_minutes, t_seconds, t_milliseconds);
  }
}
```

My questions are

1. Do I need to import the Timer.cs script into the PlayerController to get this functionality to work? If so how? (is it as simple as using a using statement?)
2. I am thinking I need to put in an additional conditional to change the win condition from false to true. Is that the right path?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You can create a boolean in Timer class inside the Update function , that false at start and if it false function work as expected. Then when you hit **12** in PlayerController script, mark it as **True**. That will stop Update function.

Comment: Inside of private void Update() { bool finished = false;} <-- Is that what you talking about when adding it to the update function? Sorry I am a little confused.

Comment: Either reference the `Timer` instance in `PlayerController` like e.g. via the Inspector in `[SerializeField] private Timer timer;` and do `if(count >= 12){ timer.enabled = false; }` or go the other way round and reference the `PlayerController` in the `Timer` e.g. in `[SerializeField] private PlayerController controller;` and do `private void Update(){ if(controller.count >= 12) { return; } ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a coroutine?

```cs
    private int _time;
    private Coroutine _cr;   

    void Start ()
    {
        //Call this to start it and save coroutine to a variable
        _cr = StartCoroutine(Timer());

       //Then to stop it call:
       //StopCoroutine(_cr);
       //And read the value of _time to get seconds since start.
    }

    private IEnumerator Timer ()
    {
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
         _time++;
         _cr = StartCoroutine(Timer());
    }
```